# How to send HTTP data and get response with Synapse (Delphi)

Tags: http, delphi, request, http-post, ararat-synapse

I think the title was clear enough.
I want to know how to send HTTP POST request with parameters/arguments and receive HTML response back - using Synapse library for Delphi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use [HttpPostURL](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/httpsend.html#HttpPostURL) function.

```
function HttpPostURL(const URL, URLData: string; const Data: TStream): Boolean;
```

`URL` - target URL
`URLData` - URL parameters; must be encoded e.g. using [EncodeURLElement](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/synacode.html#EncodeURLElement) function
`Data` - target stream, where the response will be stored

The following example uses [testing POST server](http://www.posttestserver.com/) where send two POST parameters. Note using of [EncodeURLElement](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/synacode.html#EncodeURLElement) function for encoding parameter data. If the POST succeed the server response is saved into the file.

```
uses HTTPSend, Synacode;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var URL: string;
    Params: string;
    Response: TMemoryStream;

begin
  Response := TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    URL := 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dump&html';

    Params := 'parameter1=' + EncodeURLElement('data1') + '&' +
              'parameter2=' + EncodeURLElement('data2');

    if HttpPostURL(URL, Params, Response) then
      Response.SaveToFile('c:\response.txt');

  finally
    Response.Free;
  end;
end;
```